# c++ find position of maximum value in 2D std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, max, stdvector

Suppose we have 2D vector of int like:

```
1   4   3   0
1   5   6   3
2   0   0   1
6   5   9*  3
3   5   4   2
```

Now How can I find the position of maximum value in the 2D vector: [2][3]==9 in the example above.The answer would be 2,3

I know I can use std::max_element() but it gives iterator.

Another point is that I don't want find maximum value first and then find its location using std::find() method.(Because it's not efficient)

Indeed how can I define custom compare function to do this task with single iteration.

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing vector<vector<int>> ? And how does [2][3] give 9? :S

Comment: Do you know how to iterate over a vector to find the location of the maximum? Are you aware that your index convention is not in agreement with the conventions of mathematics or computer science?

Comment: @LewsTherin nope.I have vector<vector<int>> with values.I want to get 2 and 3

Comment: Yes, `std::max_element` gives an iterator, and that's what you need.  Just subtract `your_vector.begin()` from the iterator to get the integer index.  Or use `std::distance` if you want to be more generic.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley but my vector is 2D. Can you bring example of how to use max_element?

Comment: @user1470033 swap columns with rows

Comment: @LewsTherin indices start at 0.

Comment: @daknøk Yes, but shouldn't it be [3][2]?

Comment: Batista, how big is the 2d array? Big enough to benefit from parallel processing, or not?

Comment: @PhilH It's very big. about 300000 elements in the 2D vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int Array[4][4] = { {2, 3, 4, 6}, {1, 98, 8, 22}, {12, 65, 1, 3}, {1, 7, 2, 12}};

struct location
    {
       int x;
       int y;
    };

int main()
{
    int temp = 0;
    location l;

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j< 4; j++)
            if(temp < Array[i][j])
            {
                temp = Array[i][j];
                l.x = i+ 1;
                l.y = j+ 1;
            }

            cout<<"Maximum Value is "<<temp<<" And is found at ("<<l.x<<","<<l.y<<")";
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Is the efficiency equal to max_element?

Comment: @batistacori: the answer to the question you mean is "yes".

Comment: This is `C` and not `C++`, although it uses `cout`.

Comment: Only works if all of the elements are semi-definite positive. Use `int temp = Array[0][0]` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose if it were **N*N** vector (4*4 in this case), and the name of this vector is **sum**

```
7 4 2 0 
4 8 10 8 
3 6 7 6 
3 9 19* 14
```

define a one-dimensional vector as shown below

```
vector<int> oneDimVector;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        oneDimVector.push_back(sum[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Then find out a maximum element in that one-dimensional vector as shown below

```
vector<int>::iterator maxElement;
maxElement = max_element(oneDimVector.begin(), oneDimVector.end());
```

Then find out the exact location in the matrix as shown below

```
int dist = distance(oneDimVector.begin(), maxElement);
int col = dist % 4;
int row = dist / 4;
```

Now you get the location as you expected

```
cout << "Max element is " << *maxElement << " at" << " " << row << "," << col << endl;
```

Note - we are assuming (0,0) as an initial position

Answer (score 0):

It gives the location of the element and its value in

> O(n)

time with few number of for loops.

Find the code below:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> a = { {2, 3, 4, 6}, {1, 98, 8, 22}, {12, 65, 1, 3}, {1, 7, 2, 12}};
    vector<int> tmp;

    //create 1-dimensional array to find the max element
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
        tmp.insert(tmp.end(),a[i].begin(),a[i].end());
    }

    //get the row and column location of the elment
    int row = (max_element(tmp.begin(),tmp.end()) -tmp.begin())/a.size();
    int col = (max_element(tmp.begin(),tmp.end()) -tmp.begin())%a.size();

    // gets the value of the max element in O(n) time
    int val = *max_element(tmp.begin(),tmp.end());

    cout<<"Max element is located at:"<<(row+1)<<","<<(col+1)<<"and the value is "<<val<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```